# Install compat-libstdc++-33.i686 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Tags: linux, rhel

I need to install `compat-libstdc++-33.i686` on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) without a Red Hat Network Subscription. Is there some where that I can download the required `.rpm` that suits this RHEL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

The RHEL 5 package compat-libstdc++-33 : You can get free packages from "Redhat CentOS" → → http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.7/os/i386/Packages/ . The updates are here → http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.7/updates/i386/Packages/

---

compat-libstdc++-33 : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.7/os/i386/Packages/compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686.rpm

Download the package, and ....

```
1) $ cd Downloads/
2) # yum install compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686.rpm
```

---

You can also migrate to CentOS ( get the CentOS repo files, etc.) → https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide

---

Update for CentOS 6.10 : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/ → [version] → os/ and updates/

Older CentOS versions : http://vault.centos.org/

Answer (score 3):

Update for RHEL 7 people:

I needed the same item for el7, which in RHEL world, it means adding the "optional RPMs" to your YUM repolist.

```
    $ yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

yum should be able to find and install the compat rpm now...

```
    $ yum install compat-libstdc++-33
```

Comment: For RHEL 7 on Azure, that's "yum-config-manager --enable rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-optional-rpms" (repo names are in /etc/yum.repos.d/rh-cloud.repo).